# Failed audit on "Event Flow : PHP MVC Pattern": a reference to a highly relevant book

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, low-quality-posts

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12357827 on [Event Flow : PHP MVC Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231908/event-flow-php-mvc-pattern) .

- The question can very well be closed as "too broad":

  - ["if you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you're asking for too much"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
  - the accepted answer merely gives one possible implementation example

But since it wasn't, the best possible answer is to:

- Give the very core theses on the matter (optionally, with references to further reading for more details)
- Illustrate them with a single example

The book appears to be *exactly* about what the OP is asking. So, the post could be fixed by giving the general key points from the book as well as an example for one framework, also from the book.

It's not likely that the poster *was going to do* any of that, but strictly speaking, the post isn't *"abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable"* to the point of being worthy for an audit.

Likewise, it looks unlikely the poster is affiliated with the book's author, so, noting the high relevance of the book, I gave them the benefit of the doubt.

Is the post really beyond hope and worthy to be an audit?

Comment: Someone flagged this as NAA, moderator agreed, answer got deleted, everyone ignored context. This is why we close those questions.

Comment: @Braiam Are you saying that such posts are automatically selected for audits?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/213575

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was flagged as spam - whether or not the mod intended to leave the spam flag marked helpful I'm not sure - but it's not a great audit so I've cleared the flag and re-deleted it (hopefully stopping its use as an audit) and closed the question as too broad.